# Project attributes on local secondary index with DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDBMapper to interact with DynamoDB and would like to project non-key attributes to the local secondary index that I have defined.

How do I define the projections in the model class? The annotation for secondary index does not have any property that would let me. I am not able to find any documentation anywhere.

Thanks,
Shrikant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DynamoDBMapper` will not help you project attributes to indexes.

When you create an index (either Local or Global), you will have to specify which attributes to project: `ALL`, `KEYS_ONLY` or `INCLUDE`. If you choose `INCLUDE`, you will select which attributes should be projected to the index (keys are included by default).

You can then use `DynamoDBMapper`'s `query(...)` function to retrieve items in the local secondary index you've just created.

The objects in the result of this query will only contain values for fields corresponding to the attributes that you've chosen to project, all other fields will be `null`.

So, your model class does not need to know and has nothing to do with what attributes are projected to an index. You'll have to specify those projects when you create the index.